# Android List of Expendable lists

Tags: android, listview, expandablelistview

I need to create lists of expandable list. Problem is that expandable list's height is one row. It looks like this:

[image]

If I will hardcode height as 300dp it will look like this:

[image]

Here is my code (I deleted some redundant information):

```
public class AllQuestionsListAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

private final ArrayList<QuestionsList> questionsList;
private final LayoutInflater mInflater;
private final Context context;

public AllQuestionsListAdapter(ArrayList<QuestionsList> questionsList, Context context) {
    this.questionsList = questionsList;
    this.context = context;
    this.mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View rowView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.all_question_list_item, null);
    ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder();

    vh.theme = rowView.findViewById(R.id.aq_item_list_theme);
    vh.theme.setText(questionsList.get(position).getTheme());
    vh.listView = rowView.findViewById(R.id.aq_item_list_questions);

    QuestionsExpandableListAdapter adapter = new QuestionsExpandableListAdapter(context, questionsList.get(position));
    vh.listView.setAdapter(adapter);


    return rowView;
}

static class ViewHolder{
    TextView theme;
    ExpandableListView listView;
}
}

public class QuestionsExpandableListAdapter implements ExpandableListAdapter {

private Context context;
private QuestionsList questionsList;

public QuestionsExpandableListAdapter(Context context, QuestionsList questionsList){
    this.context = context;
    this.questionsList = questionsList;
}

@Override
public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
    return questionsList.getQuestions().get(groupPosition).getQuestion();
}

@Override
public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return questionsList.getQuestions().get(groupPosition).getAnswer();
}

@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    String headerInfo = (String) getGroup(groupPosition);
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inf = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inf.inflate(R.layout.group_items, null);
    }

    TextView heading = convertView.findViewById(R.id.heading);
    heading.setText(headerInfo);
    return convertView;
}

@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    String detailInfo = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.child_items, null);
    }
    TextView childItem = convertView.findViewById(R.id.childItem);
    childItem.setText(detailInfo);

    return convertView;
}
}
```

all_question_list_item.xml:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="300dp">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/aq_item_list_theme"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:text="aaaaaaaaaaaa"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


<ExpandableListView
    android:id="@+id/aq_item_list_questions"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/aq_item_list_theme">

</ExpandableListView>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code fixed problem for me:

```
public class CustomExpandableList extends ExpandableListView {

   public CustomExpandableList(Context context) {
      super(context);
   }

   public CustomExpandableList(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
       super(context, attrs);
   }

   protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec)
   {
       heightMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(6000, MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
       super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
   }

}
```